# Is jQuery's .load() method XHR, or do web servers treat it like HTML?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to determine if I can use a line like:

```
if request.xhr?
  do something
else
  do something else
end
```

in my rails app, if I know that a particular method might be called by the .load() method in jQuery.  So, is .load() XHR, or do servers treat it like a HTML request?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by HTML request.  Any request made to your web server is an HTTP request, however.  I believe the `.xhr`? method is just checking for the `X-Requested-With` header to be set to `XMLHttpRequest`.

I believe `.load()` does set that header (as all the other jQuery ajax methods do).

Answer (score 1):

[Load allows a `data` argument](http://api.jquery.com/load/). When calling `$.load`, you could include a variable like `xhr: true`